# Simplification of powers

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, exponentiation

I think this is a really simple question, but for some reason my brain can't get round it. I am proving a combinatorial result by probabilistic method and the last step has got me really confused.

Using indicator variables for an event with probability $1/2$ happening n times at once, I get probability $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=2^{-n}$. I also know that the amount of possible n element sets this occurs in is $<2^{1-n}.$ Thus the expectation of this event occurring becomes $<2^{-n}\cdot2^{1-n}$. I need to show that this is $<1$.

This is where I am getting confused - the simplification of this!
I get:
$$2^{-n}\cdot2^{1-n}=2^{1-2n}=\frac{2^1}{2^{2n}}=\frac{2}{\left(2^2\right)^n}=\frac{2}{4^n}=\frac{1}{2^n}$$
But this is not correct. Can you explain why this doesn't work?

Also, I know that $n\geq1$ so I could say that $2^{1-2n}$ is always less than $1$ because $1-2n<1-2=-1$. Is this a valid statement instead? And would that be enough?

Comment: $2/4^n \neq 1/2^n$ unless $n=1$.

Comment: Hint: What is $\frac{2^n}{4^n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{4^n} = \frac{2}{\underbrace{4\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdots 4}_{n~ \text{copies}}} = \frac{1}{2\cdot \underbrace{4\cdot 4\cdots 4}_{n-1~\text{copies}}} = \frac{1}{2\cdot 4^{n-1}}\neq \frac{1}{2^n}$$

Here, we simplify the fraction by cancelling the two on the top with part of **one** of the fours on the bottom.  You had somehow cancelled with **all** of the fours on the bottom which is invalid.

As for your question, yes $2^{1-2n}<1$ is true for all $n\geq 1$ since $2>1$ and $1-2n\leq -1$.  If all you needed to show was that much, then what you said is (*mostly*) fine (*noting that $1-2n\leqq -1$ and not $1-2n< -1$ since the latter is untrue for $n=1$*)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your problem is that when you have something like $x^n$, it can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{x^{-n}}$. So

$$2^{1-2n} = \frac{1}{2^{-(1-2n)}} = \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}.$$

To work out the wrinkle in your logic, recall that raising something to an exponent works as a grouping symbol. When you have $\frac{2}{4^n}$, this is $2 / (4)^n$, and you can't reduce across the parenthesis because exponents come before division. It's kind of like how $(x + y)^2 \neq x^2 + y^2$ in general.